# WPC Inductive Power Transfer

Tags: inductance, wireless-charging

I am building an Inductive Power Transfer (IPT) system. As of now I am using a design based on a flyback converter. It works great but I am having issues adding features such as power control feedback from the receiver coil and load detection.

[image]

I see this has all be solved using the WPC standard as shown below.

[image]

The issues is that these WPC standard IPT systems are only 5W. My flyback design is 20W. Can anyone help me accomplish this for a 20W system?

Thanks!

Comment: "power control feedback from the receiver coil and load detection" - can you describe what it is you believe you actually need and why?

Comment: Yes, I have a receiving coid with a heating element that contains a thermo-couple. I would like the receive side to send temp data back to the transmitted in order to control a specific temperature. For detection, i need to know when the receive coil is in place and doesn't not transmit for a foreign object. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Cut out the middle man and control the heat with a simple circuit at the power-receiver-end. That's how I would do it because it keeps the control loop stable and requires very little wasted power to do this.

I have designed multi channel data monitoring systems in applications powered this way and I'm a strong believer in autonomy at the receiving end!

If you do need to send off some data then there are several ways that this can be done using independent low power rf systems. If you do need an uplink to the receiver then amplitude modulating the power carrier does work and is simple to demodulate.

Comment: So, how did the system end up running? Did you use any recommendations I made?