# Royer Oscillator

Tags: rf, oscillator

Hello everyone and thanks for your time reading this.

I recently switch my oscillator circuit over to a digital based version. With this topology I can monitor source currents on each RF MOSFETs (Q1, Q2) and monitor stability. I can also use the PWM from the microcontroller to adjust the MOSFET biasing voltages in order to control transmitting power. I also have MOSFETS to control the on/off status of the oscillator, these are Q3 and Q4.
I dont think im getting the circuit to oscillate. I am using a 40nF capacitor and a 16uH inductor for the LC tank. When I apply a PWM from 0-5 v to the gates, I detect a linearly increasing current draw. At some time in the 2 volt range the MOSFETS get really hot and a feedback sound (buzzing) is heard at the power supply and the circuit, this leads me to think the choking inductors are not adequate. When I apply a constant 5v to the MOSFET gates, the current spikes to 20+ amps and resembles a direct short circuit to ground.

Why is the circuit not oscillating and why is the MOSFET getting so hot?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your design will have a tendancy to NOT naturally start oscillating without some form of kick. Think about the DC conditions and what happens. You can ignore the individual feedback capacitors (Cc I think you call them) and what you are left with is two MOSFETs each turned fully on by the bias resistors of 1k on their respective gates. You need something that has DC as well as AC feedback I reckon. Here's a more standard circuit: -

[image]

Clearly if (say) M2 is turned on then M1 MUST be in the process of rapidly turning off due to D3. You don't have that "feature" on your circuit so there is some doubt in my mind whether your circuit *can* start oscillating without a kick of some form. May I even remind you of your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204807/wpc-inductive-power-transfer) that also used a "tried and tested" circuit: -

[image]

Why are you moving away from this design?

Finally, you got your scribbled circuit from [**this**](https://markobakula.wordpress.com/wireless-power/miniature-wireless-power-demonstrator/) website and it clearly states under the schematic this warning: -

> A concept of microcontroller supervised Royer wireless power
>   transmitter, to be utilized in future high power designs. Feedback is
>   done over capacitive coupling!

In other words, the other site (marko's science site) has not even tried this schematic and there **cannot be** any guarantees that it works without some messing around with it. Maybe YOU are Marko and you need help?

Comment: rearrange the letters Omar K ... Marko!

Comment: @BrianDrummond you are such a star!!!

Comment: Haha you guys are great. I'm not Marko, but found that circuit on a google image search. I switched from the first circuit because I did not want a center tapped coil, wanted the shunt current monitoring (which I could have done with the old design) and to have PWM control over the gates controlling transmit current (is this a good way to limit current?).

Answer (score 1):

If you prefeed your ZVS ROYER with a buck that is current limited you will stop blowing fets .When your feed is current limited you can bias your fets so thier transconductance is reasonable giving a system gain of greater than unity so it will start .If it stalls the fets are in analog mode where they will run away getting hotter and die .I got my buck convertor really simple many years ago and never looked back .I used discrete components and still do but nowdays you have more options.The buck can also soft start and this can be crucial .Textbooks say that the peak drain source volts on the fets is Pi times the supply volts which is true for steady state and if the real voltage is a good sinewave .At start up the volts can be twice this if you do not soft start so you can blow fets that you think have enough voltage rating .

Answer (score -1):

I think there needs to add resisters across each capacitor cc to discharge them. [image]

Comment: Can you draw the scenario with the tool and edit the answer?